# If $f_{n}(x) =\frac{\arctan(nx)}{\sqrt {n+x}}$ then $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly over $[0;+\infty)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

How to prove that if $$f_{n}(x) =\frac{\arctan(nx)}{\sqrt {n+x}}\space \text{for}\space n\in \mathbb{N},$$ then the functional sequence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly over the set $[0;+\infty)$?

Comment: The function value is always less than $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt n}$.

Answer (score 1):

The key observation is that the function $x \mapsto \arctan x$ is bounded on $[0, + \infty)$ by $\pi/2$, therefore
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x \in [0, +\infty)}|f_n(x) - 0| = \sup_{x \in [0, +\infty)}\frac{\arctan(nx)}{\sqrt{n + x}} \leq \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}} \to 0
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$, hence $f_n(x)$ converges to $0$ uniformly on $[0, +\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

$$|\arctan(x)|\le \pi/2$$

and

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+x}}\le\frac{1}{n}$$